# Is <title> tag default in WordPress?

Tags: theme-development, seo

This may be a stupid questions but I have been building some themes. Some of them doesn't include the `<title>` in the head and some of the theme include it.

I belive some SEO plugin can add `<meta>` tag in the head but what about title?

So, is it because the SEO plugin or it is default by WordPress included in `wp_head()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it's not a stupid question at all...

[`wp_title`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_title/) is a template tag and it was used for a long time (since 1.0.0) to put `<title>` tag in the header. This way plugins were able to modify the title with filters. In WP 4.4 it was about to be deprecated, but that idea was abandoned and you can still use that function.

On the other hand, you don't have to. [Since WP 4.1](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2014/10/29/title-tags-in-4-1/) you can use `title-tag` theme feature instead.

So if your theme declares that it supports `title-tag` feature, then the title tag will be generated automatically and you don't have to put it manually in the header any more. And to declare that you're supporting such feature you need something like this in your code:

```
function theme_slug_setup() {
   add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'theme_slug_setup' );
```

Comment: Thanks for making it clear. So the best practice would be inserting the `title-tag` support in my theme?

Comment: Yes, that's the modern way